# trying to plot Naive Bayes output but getting error - 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r, plot, naivebayes

I'm trying to plot a naive bayes output but getting

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
>      'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

I used `plot(nb)`. My dependent variable rating.text (is a factor). My independent variables mentioned are factors as well.

```
data(df)
nb<-naiveBayes(Rating.text ~  Has.Online.delivery + Has.Table.booking +
                                     Price.range + Country , data = df)
```

Please help!